# Как убрать #lorem из URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Проблема в следующем. На сайте реализованы плавные якорные ссылки через https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll
Я дилетант в джаваскрипте и jQuery, поэтому не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, подсказать, каким образом можно реализовать это не через hash или как убрать "#"?

Comment: А чем мешает # в ссылках?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/gvhTq Просто хочется, чтобы было реализовано без решётки, как на всех сайтах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал минималистический пример на jQuery. В ссылку через # записывается id блока, к которому нужно перейти, однако в URL хеши не добавляются. Работает для любой ссылки на странице, в которой указан id блока для перехода.

```js
// Page a Link Smooth Scrolling
$("[href^='#']").click(function() {
var idtop = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
$('html,body').animate(
    // Time animation
    {scrollTop: idtop}, 500);
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
div{height:100vh}
#block1{background: #000}
#block1 a{color: #fff}
</style>

<div id="block1">
<a href="#block2">скролл к следующему блоку</a>
</div>
<div id="block2">
<a href="#block1">скролл к предыдущему блоку</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("[href^='#']").click(function() {` - правильнее было бы `$("body").on('click', "[href^='#']", function() {`.

Comment: Почему? Аргументируйте.

Comment: @Qwertiy почитайте сначала эту статью и узнаете, что .on уже deprecated: https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: Не вижу в той статье, чтобы `on` был объявлен deprecated. И не обратил внимание, что ты использовал jQuery 3. Почему лучше? Потому что сработает с динамически добавленными ссылками. А твой вариант выбирает только существующие на момент выборки.

Comment: @Qwertiy походу не в этой статье читал. Или собираются убрать. Сейчас найду и скину.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а исползал последний версию хотя бы из-за того, что jQuery 3 возвращает синтаксическую ошибку, если строка селектора состоит лишь из хеша, вроде jQuery("#") или .find("#"). В старой версии $("#") возвращал пустое множество, а .find("#") — ошибку.

Answer (score 4):

Этот плагин специально построен таким образом, чтобы обрабатывать переход по кликам сохраняя их в историю. Если вам нужен просто плавный переход, может проще сделать его самому? Вот пример кода, он очень простой:

```
$('body').on('click', '.smooth-scroll-class', function(){

     //по href ищем элемент с нужным id и определяем его позицию
     pos = $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset();

     if (pos) {
        //скролим на эту позицию
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: pos.top}, 600);

        //отключаем стандартный переход по ссылке
        return false; 
     }
})
```

Так можно сделать ссылку не на `<a name='hashlink'>`  a на `<.. id='hashlink'>` Те не надо создавать якоря, достаточно прописать `id` нужному элементу.

Можно так-же и искать якорь

```
$('body').on('click', '.smooth-scroll-class', function(){

     //по href ищем якорь с нужным именем
      pos = $('a[name=' + $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/,'') + ']').offset();
     if (pos) {
         //скролим на эту позицию
         $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: pos.top}, 600);

         //отключаем стандартный переход по ссылке
         return false; 
     }

})
```

**Живой тест:**

```js
    $('body').on('click', '.smooth-scroll', function() {

      pos = $('a[name=' + $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/,'') + ']').offset();
      if (pos) {
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: pos.top
        }, 600);

        return false;
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#bottom" class='smooth-scroll'>скролл вниз</a>
<div style="height:2000px"></div>
<a name='bottom'></a>
```